# CNN autoencoder for classification purpose

Tags: regression, classification, autoencoder

I would like to use the compress layer of an AE for train a simple classifier or a regressor.
Actually the shape of the compressed layer is (64,128), so how can I transform this layer to a classification purpose ? If I use the flatten function my new layer have 8192 dimension (I suppose this is to big) 
Can someone help me ?

Here the code:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(x_train1.shape[1], x_train1.shape[2])) # 0
conv1 = Convolution1D(16, 7, activation='relu', border_mode='same', init='glorot_normal', 
                      W_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005))(input_img)  # 1
pool1 = MaxPooling1D(2, border_mode='same')(conv1)  # 2
conv2 = Convolution1D(32, 5, activation='relu', border_mode='same', init='glorot_normal', 
                      W_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005))(pool1)  # 3
pool2 = MaxPooling1D(2, border_mode='same')(conv2)  # 4
conv3 = Convolution1D(64, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', 
                      init='glorot_normal',W_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005))(pool2)  # 5
pool3 = MaxPooling1D(2, border_mode='same')(conv3)  # 6
conv4 = Convolution1D(128, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', init='glorot_normal', 
                      W_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005))(pool3)  # 7
pool4 = MaxPooling1D(2, border_mode='same')(conv4)  # 8

stack_encoded = pool4

unpool4 = UpSampling1D(2)(pool4)  # 9
deconv3 = Convolution1D(64, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', 
                        init='glorot_normal',W_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005))(unpool4)  # 10
unpool3 = UpSampling1D(2)(deconv3)  # 11
deconv2 = Convolution1D(32, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', 
                       init='glorot_normal',W_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005))(unpool3)  # 12
unpool2 = UpSampling1D(2)(deconv2)  # 13
deconv1 = Convolution1D(16, 5, activation='relu', border_mode='same', 
                        init='glorot_normal',W_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005))(unpool2)  # 14
unpool1 = UpSampling1D(2)(deconv1)  # 15
decoded = Convolution1D(1, 7, border_mode='same', 
                        init='glorot_normal',W_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005))(unpool1)  # 16
```

[Here the plot_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXXKu.png)

Thank you

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Once `Flattened` you can add a few `Dense` layers and finally a layer with the number of classes for classification with `softmax` activation. Its almost like a normal CNN classification model.

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(8192, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))
```